# Omit a pattern?

Tags: php, regex

is there a way to tell preg_match_all to find all sequences that matches a certain pattern but omits another pattern?

eg.

```
<a>computers</a>
<a>books</a>
<a>pens</a>
```

i want to match books and pens but not computers.

so using:

```
preg_match_all('/<a>.*?<\/a>', $string, $array);
```

wont do.

would appreciate some help with this. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookahead [assertions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```
/<a>(?!computer).*?<\/a>/
```